# Probability that among 3 random digits two different one

Tags: probability, combinatorics, self-learning

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

> What is the probability that among 3 random digits, there appear
>   exactly 2 different ones?

The formula for no repititions is:

```
(n*(n-1)...(n-r+1))/n^r
```

So, for the first digit there are 10 possibilities, for the second 9.
Next, the third digit should be the same as previous two: it is binomial(2,1)
And there are total 10^3 possibilities of ordering with replacement:
My formula is:

```
(10*9*binomial(2,1))/10^3
```

But it leads to the wrong answer.
 Could you please help me understand where is my mistake and the logic of solving such problems?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $10$ choices for the digit that appears twice and then $9$ choices for the digit that appears once. There are $\binom{3}{1}=3$ ways to arrange the digits.  This gives $10\cdot9\cdot3=270$ choices out of $1000$. That is, a $0.27$ probability.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!:)
I understood my mitake.

Comment: That's the important part :-) It appears that you were using $\binom{2}{1}$ instead of $\binom{3}{1}$.

Comment: And one more question, if you don't mind:
Suppose the same situation, but the questions is:
 What is the probability that among 4 random digits, there appear exactly 3 different ones?
The logic is: There are 10 choices for the digit appears twice and 9 and 8 choices for the digits appears ones.
so, there are binomial(4,3) ways to arrane the sequence.
Hence, the formula is: (10*9*8*binomial(4,3))/10^4
?

Comment: There would be $10$ choices for the first digit, $9$ choices for the second digit, and $8$ for the remaining digit. Thus, a $0.72$ probability. This leaves a $0.01$ probability for all digits the same :-)

Comment: I am sorry, but can you look one more time(i have refreshed the problem).
This topic is new for me and i am learning without teacher's help,therefore i have quite a lot of questions)

Comment: You've either changed your comment or I horribly misread it the first time. In the case of $4$ digits with $3$ different, we would need a pattern like $aabc$ There would be $10$ choices for $a$ and then $9$ for $b$ and $8$ for $c$. There would then be $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to arrange the letters. That gives $4320$ out of $10^4$ or a $0.432$ probability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i actually didn't understand why the ways of arrange digits is binomial(4,2)? Why not binomial(4,3)?

Comment: $\color{#C00000}{aa}\color{#00A000}{bc}$, $\color{#C00000}{a}\color{#00A000}{b}\color{#C00000}{a}\color{#00A000}{c}$, $\color{#C00000}{a}\color{#00A000}{bc}\color{#C00000}{a}$, $\color{#00A000}{b}\color{#C00000}{aa}\color{#00A000}{c}$, $\color{#00A000}{b}\color{#C00000}{a}\color{#00A000}{c}\color{#C00000}{a}$, $\color{#00A000}{bc}\color{#C00000}{aa}$

Comment: Think about $6$ digits with a triple and a double. There are $10$ choices for the triple, $9$ choices for the double, and $8$ choices for the singleton. Now the number of rearrangements would be $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}$ since the arrangements of the triples would count for $\binom{6}{3}$ and for each of those, the rearrangements of the double would be $\binom{3}{2}$. Thus, the probability would be $$\left.10\cdot9\cdot8\,\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\middle/10^6\right.=0.0432$$

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that you don't consider the case where the first digit repeats. You have the following exhaustive and exclusive cases:

- **The first digit repeats:** There are $10$ options for the first digit, which can appear in any of the $2$ remaining positions, and the other digit is one in $9$. There are $10 \cdot 2 \cdot 9 = 180$ cases here
- **The first digit doesn't repeat:** You can select the first digit in $10$ ways, and the other two (which repeat) in $9$ ways, for a total of $10 \cdot 9 = 90$

Adding both gives $180 + 90 = 270$ cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!:)